# How to delete file from directory using class

Tags: php

Im trying to delete a file from folder while deleting data from database. I have used a class.
I get the following error:

> Call to undefined function getCodeName()

```
//This function is to get the file name from the database
public static function getCodeName($product_id)   {
    $db = Database::getDB();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE productID = '$product_id'";
    $result = $db ->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch();
    $product = new Product ($row['productCode']);

    return $product;
}

//Delete file from folder and other data from database
public static function deleteProduct($product_id) {

    $fileName = getCodeName($product_id);
    $dir = "../images/";
    unlink($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$fileName);
    $db = Database::getDB();
    $query = "DELETE FROM products
              WHERE productID = '$product_id'";
    $row_count = $db->exec($query);
    return $row_count;
}
```

Comment: Change unlike to `unlink` http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Comment: `unlike` is currently not a php function. May be feature request for php 6.1 - LOL ....

Answer (score 1):

Use php code

`unlink()` function set full pat for delete file

Comment: Here is the error: Call to undefined function getCodeName()

Comment: change your unlike to unlink